# Highcharts: Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts, undefined

I am using certain libraries from Highcharts and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of 
undefined
at map.src.js:31
at map.src.js:22
at map.src.js:11
```

How can I fix this?
I am using:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Shiv, can you provide the code that is causing this error?

Comment: @J.Pichardo, you edited but didn't see the code hidden in the question :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faced the same issue. Highcharts released a new version [7.1.0](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/75863e2abec5fb8b7555f0d0d2340c008546dfb7) two days back. They have fixed an [issue(10232)](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10232) which is causing this error. You can use https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.14/modules/solid-gauge.js this particular version instead of the latest one. It's working for me now.

Comment: Gotta love this site, googles "error message", first hit is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you encounter this error, you might want to check that your app is not server rendered.
In the case that it is server rendered then the following should fix the issue:

Check that highcharts is a type of `'object'`, because on the server it is of type `'function'`. If it is an object then you want to execute the module you want. Kindly see below:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import highchartsBellCurve from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve';

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
  highchartsBellCurve(Highcharts); // Execute the bell curve module
}
```

Comment: Worked for me thank you. I was using nextJS.

Comment: Ran into this issue using highcharts in Storybook vs browser, constantly hitting "Cannot read property 'Core/Color/Color.js' of undefined" in the browser. This fixed it and ended several hours of pain, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was also facing the same issue... i have resolved it by replacing js files with updated version Highcharts JS v7.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I was trying to use [react-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highcharts). To resolve this, I switched to [highcharts-react-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) instead:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartSankey from "highcharts/modules/sankey";
import HighchartsWheel from "highcharts/modules/dependency-wheel";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

HighchartSankey(Highcharts);
HighchartsWheel(Highcharts);

const Viz = () => {
  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={{
        series: [{
          type: "dependencywheel",
          data: [{
            from: "Category1",
            to: "Category2",
            weight: 2
          }, {
            from: "Category1",
            to: "Category3",
            weight: 5
          }]
        }]
      }}
    />
  );
};

render(<Viz />, document.getElementById("root"));
```